# Moments of occupation time of Wiener process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

For a Brownian motion $B(t)$ defined on $[0,1]$, the occupation measure for a Borel set $A$ is defined as

$$ \mu(A)= \int_0^1 1\{B(t) \in A \}dt$$

$\mu(A)$ denotes the amount of time $B$ spends in $A$. Theorem 3.26 of Morters and Peres shows that $\mu(A)$ is a continuous random variable.

Is it known what the moments are of $\mu(A)$? Even if $A$ is an interval? A literature search hasn’t turned up anything for me yet. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Weiner $\to$ Wiener

Comment: Can you not just pull the expectation into the integral? I.e. $$\mathbb{E}[\mu(A)] = \int_0^1 \mathbb{P}[B(t) \in A] dt$$,  $$\mathbb{E}[\mu(A)^2] = \int_0^1 \int_0^1\mathbb{P}[B(t) \in A \land B(s) \in A] dt ds,$$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @a_student! That makes sense, but as the moments are increasing I wouldn’t know how to bound or compute that integral. If you can give advice on it though it would be much appreciated!

Comment: @BrownianMan I think for the higher order moments you could factorize the probabilities in the integral using the Markovianity, i.e. for $t_1 > t_2 > t_3 ... $, $\mathbb{P}[B(t_1) \in A, B(t_2) \in A, B(t_3) \in A,...] = \mathbb{P}[B(t_1) \in A| B(t_2) \in A] \mathbb{P}[B(t_2) \in A |B(t_3) \in A] ...$.